# Unable to connect port 8080 in presto-cli

Tags: presto

```
presto:tpch> show tables;
Error running command: Server refused connection: http://localhost:8080/v1/statement
presto:tpch> exit
```

I have tried adding 8080 in firewall but that is not working.

Comment: you need to elaborate your question a little more... people are more likely to give you meaningful answers for more descriptive questions

Comment: Is your Presto running? what does the server.log say?